# multinomials with large numbers in R

Tags: r

below I provide an example code, which hangs when run.  I need to calculate this figure quickly, and haven't found a suitable solution.  thanks

```
library(multicool)

A <- 0.68
B <- 0.27
C <- 0.047
D <- 0.003

nA <- 680
nB <- 270
nC <- 47
nD <- 3

x <- c(nA,nB,nC,nD)
k <- multinom(x, counts = TRUE)

prob <- (A ^ nA)*(B ^ nB)*(C ^ nC)*(D ^ nD)*(k)
```

Comment: edited, does not solve problem, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, even with this extra library, this isn't the type of problem R is made for. According to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28680+%2B+270+%2B+47+%2B+3%29%21+%2F+%28680%21+%2B+270%21+%2B+47%21+%2B+3%21%29) your `k` is equal to about 1.008 * 10^935. I'd recommend taking logs and approximating.

So, what are you doing and why do you think you need this value?

If you want to approximate, this is trivial with logs:

```
# k = (sum(x))! / x[1]! / x[2]! / x[3]! / x[4]!
```

but `log(n!) = sum(log(1:n))`, so this should be a good log approximation:

```
log.k = sum(log(1:sum(x))) - sum(log(1:x[1])) - sum(log(1:x[2])) - 
    sum(log(1:x[3])) - sum(log(1:x[4]))
```

We can define

```
p = c(A, B, C, D)
```

and then

```
log.prob = sum(x * log(p)) + log.k

> log.prob
# [1] -7.867374
```

(I found my mistake, missed a couple of the `1:` needed in the factorials.)

Or, we could use the built-in `dmultinom`

```
dmultinom(x = x, size = 1000, prob = p, log = T)
# [1] -7.867374
```

Comment: hrm, pretty disappointing... I need to be able to approximate this. This isn't about Stirling Numbers, though.

Comment: Yeah, realized I had that bit wrong. This is a reason we use log likelihoods rather than straight-up likelihoods. In this case, rather than saying "I need to do this" for a small step in the process, I think you'd be better off describing your problem and your end-goal.

Comment: marked as an answer, I need to learn log approximation! I am kicking around an idea about making an indicator function to measure abnormality of events that usually occur in a fashion that fits a normal distribution

Comment: With a bit more perspective, you could get the same answer (`exp(log.prob)` above) using `dmultinom(x = x, size = 1000, prob = p)`.

Comment: ok I'm getting things that work, quickly, and using exp(dmultinom( ... )) gives the result I got from wolfram Alpha (0.000383...), but this is without using code to multiply the probabilities.  I tried reading the dmultinom documentation to understand, but I am missing it, how can I get a better understanding of how dmultinom works?

Comment: So, if you don't set `log = T` in `dmultinom`, then you won't have to exponentiate. It's doing the same thing as my code, but probably better. It's using the [gamma function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function) for factorials, which is implemented in C. Pretty much everything in the `dmultinom` code is input checking except for `r <- lgamma(size + 1) + sum(x * log(prob) - lgamma(x + 1))`, which directly corresponds to my code.

Comment: And you realize you're just doing the [multinomial PMF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_distribution), right?